# Can we declare and use a cursor in a package specification without a body?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

It's said in database PL/SQL language reference in topic 10.1 [What is a package?](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-packages.html#GUID-8D02540E-C697-4498-9261-848F6D4E5CB5) that:

> If the public items include cursors or subprograms, then the package must also have a body. The body must define queries for public cursors and code for public subprograms.

I've tested cursor package spec without body and it worked fine (in DB version 19c):

```
create or replace package some_pak is
 cursor c is select * from employees where employee_id <102;
end;  
    
begin
  for i in some_pak.c
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i.employee_id|| ' '||i.first_name||' '|| i.salary);
  end loop;
end;
```

Result:

```
100 Steven 24000
101 Neena 17000
```

What am I doing or understanding wrong?

I am preparing for 1z0-149 exam and want to know accurate information.

Comment: Refer this (Example 6-5) : https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#GUID-05C186C1-147E-4DA6-8133-F42B24C73ADA__BABHICAF.   In your example you are defining the cursor along with declaring.

Comment: It seems the documentation is misleading on this point. Clearly you can have a cursor in a package specification and not need a package body. Perhaps there is some scenario the authors had in mind when they wrote that, but I can't think of one.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit misleading, but if you take the previous paragraph from the documentation into account:

> A package always has a specification, which declares the public items that can be referenced from outside the package.

... and stress the *declares* in that, then it sort of makes sense; if you only declare a cursor, rather than declaring and defining as your example does, then you do need a body too. For example, your specification could do:

```
create or replace package some_pak is
 cursor c return dual%rowtype;
end;
/
```

But if you tried to reference that cursor you'd get "ORA-04067: not executed, package body ... does not exist".

You would then need to define the cursor in the package body, e.g.:

```
create or replace package body some_pak is
 cursor c return dual%rowtype is
   select * from dual;
end;
/
```

Notice that you need to declare the return type, in both the specification and body. In your original version that isn't necessary, but here the declaration still has to tell callers the structure of the data the cursor will return. That is the API contract, if you like.

Declaring and defining the cursor separately means you can redefine the cursor by recompiling just the package body (as long as the projection remains the same, of course), avoiding invalidating anything that refers to it - as would happen if you recompiled the specification.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e2d732d9d8d3fd6705f6b075898bdbbe)

Splitting the declaration and definition would also allow you to hide (albeit not very securely) the actual cursor query by wrapping the package body, without wrapping the specification. Whether that would ever be useful is another matter, but thought it might be worth mentioning anyway.